# Download/cache osmdroid maps programmatically from Android app

Tags: android, maps, openstreetmap, offline, osmdroid

Is it possible to programatically from an Android app to export maptiles from osm?

Or to force a specific area to be cached?

I am trying to create an app that can cache/download an area of the map programmatically so it can be available offline when needed.

It doesn't have to be osm but from what i've read doing it for google maps would violate theirs terms of service.

If someone could point me in the right direction i would appreciate it.
Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 2):

Mobile Atlas Creator works perfectly, but having similar feature directly integrated in Android app would much simpler for end-users.

There is a thread about this subject in the osmdroid Discussion Group, here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/osmdroid/u0SXXzqHg4U

If you want this feature, don't hesitate to "vote" for it in the Discussion Group thread (10 votes requested :-).

Comment: Yes, it's available in osmbonuspack now.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/). But note that even "free" servers don't necessarily allow you to bulk-download tiles. See osm's [Tile Usage Policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy) for example. Alternately, you can download the raw osm data and run your own Tile Server.